# terraform-providers/mysql does not have a package available for your current platform - Mac M1

Tags: terraform, command-line-interface, hashicorp

I've been trying to run the `terraform init` command locally but got this error.

```
Error: Incompatible provider version
Provider registry.terraform.io/terraform-providers/mysql v1.9.0 does not have a package available for your current platform, darwin_arm64.
```

I've been looking for the latest terrform-providers/mysql on the [terraform website](https://registry.terraform.io/browse/providerswebsite) but got no luck yet.

Also, for the command, I think it's one of the issues with Mac M1. Do you know what should be done for this issue.

Please help if you have any idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: there's no official  provider ,but this one looks good : https://registry.terraform.io/providers/Giphy/mysql/latest

Comment: Please share the `required_providers` block in your config.

Comment: Hi @MattSchuchard, here is the required_providers that I'm using
```mysql = {
      source  = "terraform-providers/mysql"
      version = "~> 1.6"
    }```

Answer (score 1):

Please try with tfenv : https://github.com/tfutils/tfenv

```
brew uninstall terraform

brew install tfenv

TFENV_ARCH=amd64 tfenv install 1.0.0

tfenv use 1.0.0
```